# execve(2) not launching system commands

Tags: c, system-calls, namespace, container, clone

I am trying to implement a container, and for that I create a process using the clone(2) system call with the appropriate flags:

```
  if ((child_pid = clone(child_main, process_struct.Stack + process_struct.StackPtr,
   CLONE_NEWCGROUP
  |CLONE_NEWIPC
  |CLONE_NEWNET
  |CLONE_NEWNS
  |CLONE_NEWPID
  |CLONE_NEWUTS
  |SIGCHLD, &process_struct, checkpoint)) == -1){
     fprintf(stderr,"Failed...%m \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  }else{
    fprintf(stderr,"Done\n");
    waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
  }
```

inside child_main() I Change the host name for the process's namespace, also i set the mount namespace, I installed a Linux file system hierarchy on a partition like a normal Linux installation (I did that to create a clean file system image clean of my files and binaries) and then I set the propagation type to MS_UNBINDABLE, then I pivot_root(2) to change my process's root directory.

```
const int child_main(struct process *process_struct, int *checkpoint){

  char c;
  fprintf(stderr,"=> IPC setup...");
  //double check the IPC
  close(checkpoint[1]);
  fprintf(stderr,"Done\n");

  if ( sethostname(process_struct->Hostname, 
strlen(process_struct->Hostname)) || mounting(process_struct)){
    return -1;
  }

  // startup the IPC pipes
  read(checkpoint[0], &c, 1);

  if(execve("/bin/bash", (char*)0, NULL) == -1 ){
    fprintf(stderr,"--> Launching process Failed %m\n");
    return -1;
  }
    return 0;

}
```

The problem is that my system goes over the execve(2) and does not launch the /bin/bash and the program flows without errors. When I add system(2) statement before the execve(2) : `system("ls");` it lists the appropriate file system and current working directory. Also when I change the execve(2) paramters to either: 
`execve("/bin/ls", (char*)0, NULL)` or `execve("/bin/pstree", (char*)0, NULL)` or any other parameter it will return an error of: **No such file or directory** or **A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call**, also when I strace my program at the execve(2) system call it gives: **NULL, 0, NULL)             = 17992**

update: the error has nothing to do with the file system image, I have performed more tests and are as the follwoing, I used for my mount namespaces my system's filesystem not the one I installed on a partition and running /bin/bash doesn't still work, I created a simple C program and compiled it, and it ran fine so there is something wrong that prevent bin/bash from being executed, to further test these results I reused for my mount namespaces the file system from my I moved the same executable to the file system first under `"/"` and second under the same path
**my main system path to the executable=** `/home/omar/docs/test.out`
**my mounted file system from the partition path to the executable=** `/home/omar/docs/test.out` 
since I wanted to check if the same path might have caused a confusion while adding to each executable a statment so can tell which path did my program take, and it worked fine without any problem and correctly as expected, so the problem is just that system essential commands will not work.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn’t launch it, and then `bash` exits immediately?

Comment: yes, also the parent program resumes normally.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, `execve` would replace the program if it succeeded...

Comment: What happens if you pass a valid argv array to execve?

Comment: execve(2) will launch /bin/bash and replace the program, then it will exit immediately, as if the /bin/bash doesn't actually launch, in the question I specified what strace shows me at execve(2) which is ``` NULL, 0, NULL) = 17992```

Comment: @o.awajan Are you sure? On failure, execve return -1. Anyway, from Linux execve manpage On Linux, argv can be specified as NULL, which has the same effect as specifying this argument as a pointer to a list containing a single NULL pointer. Do not take advantage of this misfeature! It is nonstandard and nonportable: on most other UNIX systems doing this will result in an error (EFAULT).

Comment: I tried ```NULL```, instead of ```(char*)0``` and it doesn't work either, also I am launching /bin/bash, it doesn't take arguments,  so what should i specify as arguments?

Comment: `NULL` is no different from `(char*)0`, except when passed to a variadic function, when it may actually end up being only a half of a pointer, and p0wn you ;-). You should always specify at least an argument to a program started with execve -- its name. Just change your `execve(...)` to `execl("/bin/bash", "bash", (void*)0)` and see what happens.

Comment: As to `bash` exiting immediately it may have to do with it not being able to find the `/proc/self/fd/` or `/dev/null` files within the new namespace -- but that's only a conjecture, because I'm not able to test anything now.

Comment: @mosvy, I do believe what just said to be the case, as I said I mounted the linux root file system from a linux installtion on another partition and since I didn't actually boot that partition my ```/proc``` is empty and my process can't find it's ```/proc/self/fd```, but I find it weird cause the mount namespace should only be for the filesystem as in only a view, also I am trying to launch the executable ```/bin/bash``` from the mounted file system not my system's ```bin/bash```, does that sound correct? and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please do check the question again, I have updated it with new findings.